# Solving Fulton and Harris exercise 2.4

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho$ be a representation of $G$ on $V$ of dimension $4$. let $g\in G$ be an element of order 4.Let $\chi$  the character of  representation $V$ is known then find the eigenvalues of $\rho_g$.

Clearly,the Characteristic polynomial of $\rho_g$ divides $x^4 -1$.But I don't see how to use Character function to find eigenvalues.Please help!

Comment: Is the representation irreducible? Otherwise you cannot tell from the information given.

Comment: No nothing is given.It is an exercise problem in Fulton and Harris.

Comment: Then this is simply impossible. There is no way to recover eigenvalues from information given. Are you sure there are no standing hypotheses or something?

Comment: @AdamHughes yes,nothing is missing.

Comment: Please provide the exercise number from Fulton–Harris.

Answer (score 0):

From the value of $\chi(g^{2})$ you can know the how many of the eigenvalues are $\pm 1$ and how many are $\pm i$. With this information at hand, you can use the value of $\chi(g)$ to determine the precise eigenvalues.

Comment: Sorry,Can u explain a little bit more?